# Using seq() and rep() function in R

Tags: r

I need to do the following in R:
I have a number (N), for example `N <- 7`
and I have a length (size), for example `size <- 3`

And for example if N==7 and size==3, I need to get an output a vector same as:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

you see in v, each number from 1 to size is repeated N times. Is there any way to do this in R  without using a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
 rep(seq(size), each=N)
```